# Apps aren't loaded yet (when learning signals)

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm trying to learn signals. In the apps.py below there is a couple of commented lines. As soon as I uncomment from .models import ReceiverModel, SenderModel, I get django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Could you help me understand what I am doing wrongly?

**demo_signals/my_app/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class SenderModel(models.Model):
    pass

class ReceiverModel(models.Model):
    pass

    @receiver(post_save, sender=SenderModel)
    def my_callback(self, sender, **kwargs):
        print("Saving finished!")
```

**demo_signals/demo_signals/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig',
]
```

**demo_signals/my_app/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import Signal
#from .models import ReceiverModel, SenderModel


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

    def ready(self):
        print("Here")
        #Signal.connect(self, ReceiverModel, SenderModel)
```

**Some part of the traceback**

```
  File "/home/michael/workspace/demo_signals/my_app/apps.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import ReceiverModel, SenderModel
  File "/home/michael/workspace/demo_signals/my_app/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class SenderModel(models.Model):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/PhotoArchive/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/PhotoArchive/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 240, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/PhotoArchive/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready), you can't import your models that way in your `AppConfig`, instead you need to do:

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

    def ready(self):
        ReceiverModel = self.get_model('ReceiverModel')
        SenderModel = self.get_model('SenderModel')
        Signal.connect(self, ReceiverModel, SenderModel)
```